# How to crawl multiple domains using single crawler?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

How can I crawl data from multiple domains using a single crawler. I have done crawling of single sites using beautiful soup but couldn't figure out how to create a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Well this question is flawed, sites that you want to scrape have to have something in common for instance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
import urllib.request

for counter in range(0,10):        
    # site = input("Type the name of your website") Python 3+
    site = raw_input("Type the name of your website")
    # Takes the website you typed and stores it in > site < variable
    make_request_to_site = request.urlopen(site).read()
    # Makes a request to the site that we stored in a var
    soup = BeautifulSoup(make_request_to_site, "html.parser")
    # We pass it through BeautifulSoup parser in this case html.parser
    # Next we make a loop to find all links in the site that we stored
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        print link['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, each site has their own distinct setup for selectors (, , etc). A single generic crawler won't be able to go into a url and intuitively understand what to scrape.

BeautifulSoup might not be the best choice for this type of request. Scrapy is another web crawler library that's a bit more robust that BS4.

Similar question here on stackoverflow: [Scrapy approach to scraping multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160673/scrapy-approach-to-scraping-multiple-urls)

Scrapy Documentation: 
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html